# What modifications do I need to make to my gcloud command to get the list of enabled services in all GCP projects in the below tabular format?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have the following code block to enumerate the enabled services in all GCP projects:

```
for project in  $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)"); \
do gcloud services list --project $project --format="table[box]($project,config.name,config.title)"; \
done;
```

It gives me the output in this format:

[image]

But I would like the output to be in this format:

[image]

How do I accomplish that? Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't using `gcloud` because you need to assemble values from multiple commands: Projects.List and Services.List. `gcloud --format` applies only to the output from a single command.

You're grabbing all the data you need (Project, Name and Title). I recommend you use bash and the characters output by `gcloud` to form the table, and synthesize the table output for yourself.

##### Update

Here's a script that'll get you CSV output that matches your rows:

```sh
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")
for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  CONFIGS=$(gcloud services list \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="csv[no-heading](config.name,config.title.encode(base64))")
  for CONFIG in ${CONFIGS}
  do
    IFS=, read NAME TITLE <<< ${CONFIG}
    TITLE=$(echo ${TITLE} | base64 --decode)
    echo "${PROJECT},${NAME},\"${TITLE}\""
  done
done
```

> **NOTE** [`encode(base64)`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections#encode) to avoid the unquote `title` values from being split. `base64 --decode` reverses this at output. It should be possible to use [`format`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections#encode) but I don't understand the syntax. `--format='csv[no-heading](config.name,format("\"{0}\"",config.title))'` didn't work.

Then, in the best *nix tradition, you can pipe that output into awk or columns or some other script that formats the CSV as a pretty-printed table. This is the more difficult challenge because you'll want to determine the longest value in each field in order to layout correctly. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you observe my command closely, it is actually a bash command. It does query all projects and gives me the desired results. The problem here is, I couldn't get to display the results in the exact format I need. If you can recommend any modifications to the above command, then that would be very helpful.

Comment: I understand. I'm familiar with `gcloud`. You can't get a single table from multiple `gcloud`commands. You need to use more (!) bash to create the result manually.

Comment: Hey @DazWilkin, your script helped. Thanks.